# Item based permissions: View list items minus access contents of that item (contents of document set)

Tags: item-level-permissions

Is it possible to block access to specific items while still providing an overview off all list items?

Idea: Everyone should be able to view all projects that are currently in progress.However, only those people who are actually working on the project = are "assigned to" the project should be able to access/view/edit the item . Therefore i created item-level permissions for each item (document set); permissions not inherited

The problem: all users of my site have read only permissions because they should be able to view/search all projects (overview) - but not the contents. Those who have only read permissions(everyone else) are still able to click on the list item and are also still able to download some of the contents . I looked into setting up an information rights policy but do not have admin rights. Audience targeting doesnt seem to work either, since i would have to create a new group for each project.

Is there any way i can prevent users without contribute/edit permissions from accessing/viewing the contents of the list items?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is a separate link list for your projects with all publicly available information that everyone has at least read access to.  Then provide a link on the item to the project document set where there are more restrictive permissions.  This requires kind of a duplicate creation process, but gives you the security separation.

Comment: If you need to/have access, use SPD or an event receiver to create the new link list item when a new document set is created.